# Can access VM Guest IP from Host but not from other computer on same LAN

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, centos, vmware-player

I am hosting a web application on a Linux (CentOS 6.7) Virtual Machine guest, that is sitting on a Windows 7 host.  I have configured a `bridged network connection` between the host and the guest, and the guest has it's own `Static IP Address`.

For the longest time, I could not access the Guest Static IP Address at Port 3838.  The browser page would time out.  I could ping the guest but I could not load the web application that I was hosting on Port 3838 in the guest.

I finally disabled `iptables` within the guest and I am NOW able to load the web application from the host at `Guest_IP_Address:3838`.

But, I cannot access the web application at `Guest_IP_Address:3838` from another computer on the network (on the same LAN).  Any ideas why I can access the Guest IP and web application from the host, but not from any other computer on the network?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by:

1. I disabled `iptables`
   http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-turn-off-firewall-in-linux/
2. Instead of listening on Port 3838, I changed my server.conf file to listen on Port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with a development VM on my desktop at work and I finally nailed it down to being my Antivirus program. The license expired and was practically useless anyways, but once I uninstalled it and rebooted it, I was able to get in no problem. Check the firewall and antivirus settings on your Windows 7 host (try tuning them off temporarily) and see if you are then able to access the web application on another computer on the network.